# Entity double in query after save

Tags: breeze

I am using Breeze to create a dynamic data edit grid. After I add a new entity to the manager, edit the properties, save it to a WebAPI service and make a local query, I get the same entity twice. One entity is with the server generated key in entitystate unchanged, the other is with primarykey -1 and in entitystate added.

Don't really know what I am doing wrong or did'nt understand the mechanics behind Breeze.

Note.

I am using a custom contextprovider with the savechanges method overridden. I am returning in the keymap the entity type, realvalue (DB generated key), tempvalue (key that was assigned by Breeze, e.g. -1).

EDIT.

I solved the problem. I had a bug in my custom contextprovider. I forget to actually add the keymap I was generating to the result of the savechangescore method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, i had a bug in my custom contextprovider. I forget to actually add the keymap i was generating to the result ov the savechangescore method.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is whether you are actually saving an Entity with the temporary key (i.e. -1).

If this is the case, ( which you clearly do NOT want), then it is likely that this entityType does not have a correct 'AutoGeneratedKeyType' in its metadata. You can check this by calling the MetadataStore.getEntityType method and inspecting the metadata.

If this is not the case, then please post the code to your custom contextprovider.

Comment: Hey, i checked the Metadata. I have the autoGeneratedKeyType property with name = "Identity". I presume this means that breeze knows that the key is being generated by the database ??

Comment: PS, i didnt override the metadata method of the entity framework context provider

Comment: Ok, since the metadata looks good and since I cannot repro your issue , I am guessing that it has something to do with your custom contextProvider.  So please go ahead and send an email to me (Jay Traband) at breeze@ideablade.com with the source for your contextProvider ( or post it here). Also it might be worth trying your code without the custom contextProvider and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Did you SET the id on the client to -1 yourself? You shouldn't. Breeze will only generate a temp key if it starts in the default value (0). Let Breeze generate that key for you (or you can override the client-side key generator ... but why bother?). I'm also surprised to hear that you are managing the keymap on the server yourself. Why is that? You may have a good reason but it is curious.

Comment: No, i am not setting any id on the client. The -1 is breeze generated.

Comment: Also, i have just tried with the standard entity framework context provider and the same problem occurs.

Comment: In your SaveChangesCore implementation, I notice that you are not calling the base implementation which handles returning the correct keymap. Also, your version doesn't actually seem to perform an EF Save.  We probably need to document this better, but I'm still confused about why you needed to override SaveChangesCore.

Comment: I don't want to call the standard implementation of the SaveChangesCore(). I am using my own mechanism to save the data to the database using a generic repository class that handles different things

Comment: And by not calling the SaveChangesCore() i am trying to avoid a dublicate save